# Can someone help me decipher this traceback output?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a GRM IRT on a scale I am developing for my PhD. It is 35 items and uses ordinal data.

I wanted to compute my discriminant and used this script:

```
out<-grm(data)
```

However, this error message has come up:

```
Error in log.pr[xj, ] : only 0's may be mixed with negative subscripts
```

I ran a traceback () and the output came up as this:

> 4: fn(par, ...)
>   3: (function (par) 
>      fn(par, ...))(c(-6.35437004079735, -0.364004849267593, -0.898429233151104, 
>      -1.23984596114272, -1.49212906457366, -1.69241522473505, -1.85849812710349, 
>      -2.00033164040792, -2.12406114926494, -2.23375198323263, -2.33223507272314, 
>      -2.42156170349994, -2.50326618700921, -2.5785263539754, -2.64826617920226, 
>      -2.71322391775684, -2.77399879768055, -2.83108389451058, -2.88488982415199, 
>      -2.93576217056118, -2.98399453762421, -3.02983848132802, -3.07351117665916, 
>      -3.11520141244305, -3.15507433360397, -3.19327523242902, -3.22993260894426, 
>      -3.2651606632635, -3.29906134193651, -3.33172603078752, -3.36323696509952, 
>      -3.39366841196259, -3.42308766758587, -3.45155590327634, -3.47912888683431, 
>      -3.50585760075627, -3.53178877446963, -3.55696534455883, -3.58142685436845, 
>      -3.60520980232064, -3.62834794664975, -3.65087257293855, -3.67281272977613, 
>      -3.6941954369902, -3.715045870197, -3.73538752482965, -3.75524236232386, 
>      -3.77463094074087, -3.79357253177428, -3.81208522580977, -3.83018602647178, 
>      -3.8478909358957, -3.86521503179558, -3.88217253725742, -3.89877688406662, 
>      -3.9150407702749, -3.9309762126255, -3.94659459437652, -3.96190670900033, 
>      -3.97692280017728, -3.99165259845579, -4.00610535490539, -4.02028987205552, 
>      -4.03421453237699, -4.04788732453823, -4.06131586764033, -4.07450743361585, 
>      -4.08746896795528, -4.10020710890893, -4.11272820529674, -4.12503833304585, 
>      -4.13714331056276, -4.1490487130378, -4.16075988576956, -4.17228195658841, 
>      -4.183619847452, -4.19477828527704, -4.20576181206797, -4.21657479439593, 
>      -4.22722143227764, -4.23770576749893, -4.24803169142479, -4.25820295233258, 
>      -4.2682231623034, -4.27809580370343, -4.28782423528344, -4.29741169792385, 
>      -4.30686132004937, -4.31617612273596, -4.32535902453054, -4.33441284600319, 
>      -4.34334031404888, -4.35214406595523, -4.36082665325186, -4.3693905453544, 
>      -4.37783813301706, -4.38617173160494, -4.394393584198, -4.40250586453592, 
>      -4.41051067981497, -4.41841007334427, -4.42620602707081, -4.43390046398064, 
>      -4.44149525038319, -4.44899219808597, -4.45639306646539, -4.46369956444013, 
>      -4.47091335235175, -4.47803604375878, -4.48506920714788, -4.49201436756743, 
>      -4.49887300818773, -4.50564657179055, -4.51233646219396, -4.51894404561359, 
>      -4.52547065196522, -4.53191757611077, -4.53828607905125, -4.54457738906914, 
>      -4.55079270282223, -4.55693318639258, -4.56299997629119, -4.5689941804222, 
>      -4.57491687900746, -4.58076912547375, -4.58655194730426, -4.59226634685705, 
>      -4.59791330214996, -4.60349376761578, -4.60900867482787, -4.61445893319729, 
>      -4.61984543064409, -4.62516903424216, -4.630430590841, -4.63563092766262, 
>      -4.6407708528778, -4.64585115616023, -4.65087260922029, -4.65583596632032, 
>      -4.6607419647698, -4.66559132540447, -4.6703847530469, -4.67512293695182, 
>      -4.67980655123518, -4.68443625528853, -4.68901269417905, -4.69353649903561, 
>      -4.69800828742169, -4.70242866369596, -4.70679821936018, -4.71111753339555, 
>      -4.71538717258819, -4.71960769184348, -4.7237796344903, -4.72790353257487, 
>      -4.7319799071457, -4.73600926852875, -4.73999211659402, -4.74392894101372, 
>      -4.74782022151185, -4.75166642810625, -4.75546802134308, -4.75922545252369, 
>      -4.76293916392464, -4.7666095890109, -4.77023715264254, -4.77382227127506, 
>      -4.77736535315361, -4.78086679850138, -4.78432699970235, -4.78774634147854, 
>      -4.79112520106213, -4.79446394836214, -4.79776294612658, -4.80102255009957, 
>      -4.80424310917428, -4.80742496554081, -4.81056845483035, -4.81367390625493, 
>      -4.81674164274318, -4.81977198107251, -4.82276523199699, -4.82572170037214, 
>      -4.82864168527594, -4.83152548012652, -4.83437337279665, -4.83718564572486, 
>      -4.83996257602354, -4.84270443558434, -4.84541149118027, -4.84808400456532, 
>      -4.85072223257099, -4.85332642720076, -4.85589683572149, -4.85843370075262, 
>      -4.86093726035288, -4.86340774810464, -4.86584539319616, -4.86825042050155, 
>      -4.87062305065852, -4.87296350014423, -4.87527198134896, -4.8775487026481, 
>      -4.87979386847195, -4.88200767937382, -4.88419033209636, -4.88634201963612, 
>      -4.8884629313066, -4.89055325279924, -4.89261316624316, -4.89464285026329, 
>      -4.89664248003717, -4.89861222734961, -4.90055226064674, -4.90246274508818, 
>      -4.90434384259799, -4.90619571191436, -4.90801850863795, -4.90981238527868, 
>      -4.91157749130209, -4.91331397317364, -4.91502197440238, -4.91670163558322, 
>      -4.91835309443832, -4.91997648585718, -4.921571941936, -4.92313959201551, 
>      -4.9246795627182, -4.92619197798463, -4.92767695910844, -4.92913462477067, 
>      -4.93056509107303, -4.93196847157044, -4.9333448773025, -4.93469441682455, 
>      -4.93601719623711, -4.93731331921522, -4.93858288703667, -4.93982599860963, 
>      -4.94104275049921, -4.94223323695355, -4.94339754992892, -4.94453577911457, 
>      -4.94564801195636, -4.94673433367991, -4.947794827313, -4.94882957370765, 
>      -4.94983865156093, -4.95082213743582, -4.95178010578068, -4.95271262894885, 
>      -4.95361977721718, -4.95450161880416, -4.95535821988729, -4.95618964461996, 
>      -4.95699595514793, -4.95777721162502, -4.95853347222833, -4.95926479317287, 
>      -4.9599712287257, -4.96065283121967, -4.96130965106649, -4.96194173676916, 
>      -4.96254913493415, -4.96313189028305, -4.96369004566357, -4.96422364206019, 
>      -4.96473271860417, -4.96521731258329, -4.96567745945099, -4.96611319283512, 
>      -4.96652454454616, -4.96691154458486, -4.96727422114972, -4.96761260064392, 
>      -4.96792670768166, -4.96821656509404, -4.96848219393476, -4.96872361348516, 
>      -4.96894084125911, -4.96913389300686, -4.96930278271906, -4.96944752263021, 
>      -4.96956812322158, -4.96966459322367, -4.96973693961833, -4.96978516764046, 
>      -4.96980928077927, -4.96980928077926, -4.96978516764046, -4.9697369396183, 
>      -4.9696645932237, -4.9695681232216, -4.96944752263025, -4.96930278271901, 
>      -4.96913389300687, -4.9689408412591, -4.96872361348515, -4.96848219393476, 
>      -4.968216565094, -4.96792670768169, -4.96761260064393, -4.96727422114976, 
>      -4.96691154458481, -4.96652454454617, -4.96611319283512, -4.96567745945096, 
>      -4.9652173125833, -4.96473271860414, -4.96422364206023, -4.96369004566356, 
>      -4.9631318902831, -4.96254913493411, -4.96194173676918, -4.96130965106645, 
>      -4.96065283121964, -4.95997122872573, -4.95926479317283, -4.95853347222839, 
>      -4.957777211625, -4.95699595514799, -4.95618964461992, -4.95535821988729, 
>      -4.95450161880413, -4.95361977721718, -4.95271262894888, -4.95178010578064, 
>      -4.95082213743583, -4.94983865156096, -4.94882957370767, -4.94779482731299, 
>      -4.94673433367991, -4.94564801195633, -4.94453577911457, -4.94339754992895, 
>      -4.94223323695351, -4.94104275049926, -4.93982599860963, -4.9385828870367, 
>      -4.93731331921516, -4.93601719623713, -4.93469441682454, -4.9333448773025, 
>      -4.93196847157044, -4.93056509107299, -4.92913462477072, -4.92767695910844, 
>      -4.92619197798467, -4.92467956271816, -4.92313959201552, -4.92157194193597, 
>      -4.91997648585717, -4.91835309443834, -4.9167016355832, -4.91502197440241, 
>      -4.91331397317363, -4.91157749130212, -4.90981238527865, -4.90801850863795, 
>      -4.90619571191435, -4.90434384259796, -4.90246274508821, -4.90055226064671, 
>      -4.89861222734964, -4.89664248003716, -4.89464285026335, -4.89261316624311, 
>      -4.89055325279925, -4.8884629313066, -4.88634201963611, -4.88419033209637, 
>      -4.88200767937376, -4.87979386847201, -4.8775487026481, -4.875271981349, 
>      -4.87296350014419, -4.87062305065855, -4.86825042050152, -4.86584539319613, 
>      -4.86340774810465, -4.86093726035284, -4.85843370075268, -4.85589683572149, 
>      -4.85332642720079, -4.85072223257096, -4.84808400456533, -4.84541149118027, 
>      -4.84270443558431, -4.83996257602355, -4.8371856457248, -4.83437337279671, 
>      -4.83152548012652, -4.82864168527598, -4.82572170037208, -4.82276523199705, 
>      -4.81977198107246, -4.81674164274317, -4.81367390625495, -4.81056845483033, 
>      -4.80742496554085, -4.80424310917426, -4.80102255009964, -4.79776294612652, 
>      -4.79446394836217, -4.79112520106211, -4.78774634147853, -4.78432699970237, 
>      -4.78086679850133, -4.77736535315365, -4.77382227127504, -4.7702371526426, 
>      -4.76660958901086, -4.76293916392465, -4.75922545252368, -4.75546802134305, 
>      -4.75166642810629, -4.7478202215118, -4.74392894101376, -4.73999211659402, 
>      -4.7360092685288, -4.73197990714565, -4.7279035325749, -4.72377963449028, 
>      -4.71960769184346, -4.71538717258821, -4.7111175333955, -4.7067982193602, 
>      -4.70242866369598, -4.69800828742174, -4.69353649903556, -4.6890126941791, 
>      -4.68443625528848, -4.67980655123514, -4.67512293695186, -4.67038475304688, 
>      -4.66559132540449, -4.6607419647698, -4.65583596632032, -4.65087260922031, 
>      -4.64585115616023, -4.64077085287778, -4.6356309276626, -4.63043059084102, 
>      -4.62516903424216, -4.61984543064409, -4.61445893319726, -4.60900867482792, 
>      -4.60349376761576, -4.59791330214998, -4.592266346857, -4.58655194730426, 
>      -4.58076912547375, -4.57491687900746, -4.56899418042224, -4.56299997629114, 
>      -4.55693318639263, -4.55079270282223, -4.54457738906914, -4.53828607905125, 
>      -4.53191757611073, -4.52547065196524, -4.51894404561357, -4.512336462194, 
>      -4.50564657179051, -4.49887300818775, -4.49201436756745, -4.48506920714788, 
>      -4.47803604375876, -4.47091335235171, -4.46369956444017, -4.45639306646537, 
>      -4.448992198086, -4.44149525038316, -4.43390046398068, -4.42620602707079, 
>      -4.41841007334431, -4.41051067981494, -4.40250586453589, -4.39439358419804, 
>      -4.38617173160493, -4.37783813301709, -4.36939054535436, -4.36082665325188, 
>      -4.35214406595523, -4.34334031404891, -4.33441284600316, -4.32535902453051, 
>      -4.31617612273599, -4.30686132004936, -4.29741169792389, -4.2878242352834, 
>      -4.27809580370348, -4.26822316230337, -4.2582029523326, -4.24803169142479, 
>      -4.23770576749888, -4.22722143227767, -4.21657479439592, -4.205761812068, 
>      -4.19477828527701, -4.18361984745203, -4.1722819565884, -4.16075988576959, 
>      -4.14904871303779, -4.13714331056271, -4.12503833304589, -4.11272820529671, 
>      -4.10020710890894, -4.08746896795528, -4.07450743361588, -4.06131586764028, 
>      -4.04788732453828, -4.03421453237697, -4.02028987205547, -4.00610535490546, 
>      -3.99165259845574, -3.97692280017733, -3.96190670900028, -3.94659459437657, 
>      -3.93097621262548, -3.91504077027494, -3.89877688406658, -3.8821725372574, 
>      -3.86521503179562, -3.84789093589566, -3.83018602647182, -3.81208522580973, 
>      -3.79357253177432, -3.77463094074085, -3.7552423623239, -3.73538752482962, 
>      -3.71504587019698, -3.69419543699024, -3.6728127297761, -3.65087257293858, 
>      -3.62834794664972, -3.60520980232067, -3.58142685436842, -3.55696534455887, 
>      -3.5317887744696, -3.50585760075626, -3.47912888683434, -3.45155590327632, 
>      -3.4230876675859, -3.39366841196256, -3.36323696509956, -3.33172603078748, 
>      -3.29906134193655, -3.26516066326348, -3.22993260894422, -3.19327523242906, 
>      -3.15507433360394, -3.11520141244309, -3.07351117665912, -3.02983848132806, 
>      -2.98399453762419, -2.93576217056121, -2.88488982415196, -2.83108389451055, 
>      -2.77399879768059, -2.71322391775682, -2.64826617920229, -2.57852635397537, 
>      -2.50326618700924, -2.42156170349991, -2.33223507272318, -2.2337519832326, 
>      -2.12406114926491, -2.00033164040795, -1.85849812710346, -1.69241522473508, 
>      -1.49212906457363, -1.23984596114276, -0.898429233151078, -0.364004849267639, 
>      0.0946177439853685, -2.79796308473647, -0.225010673029408, -0.647699465173936, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, 0.0167055173176093, 
>      -2.4643978084541, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.22501067302941, -0.0448461383151263, -3.43570543761185, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866, -0.9747299419738, 
>      -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.0396822628273134, -1.31559338215418, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, 
>      -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866002, -0.647699465173935, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.00171911145555971, -0.547695558660466, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866, -0.9747299419738, -1.00883617472156, 
>      -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866002, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, 
>      0.0131710472594018, -1.04748302422711, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, 
>      -0.864615530866002, -0.647699465173934, -0.22501067302941, 0.0488279080228325, 
>      -2.49257383632563, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866002, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.22501067302941, 0.00693887674107702, -2.99949083915066, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.9747299419738, 
>      -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.0224283994321747, -2.99293375386241, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, 
>      -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.0585858269782392, -3.64680952295603, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, 
>      -0.864615530866, -0.9747299419738, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973799, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, 0.0474899689336967, 
>      -1.54962493751838, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173935, -0.22501067302941, -0.0149734715041794, -2.00206982774229, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173936, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, 
>      -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, 
>      -0.22501067302941, 0.00291069195599297, -1.41120233183471, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, 
>      -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866002, -0.647699465173935, -0.225010673029409, 
>      0.0220011657226189, -3.29241556310429, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.9747299419738, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, -0.148374240388796, 
>      -2.97418808195519, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.9747299419738, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, -0.0026146265050107, 
>      -2.60262977534019, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, -0.0547045162426989, 
>      -2.07163480783627, -0.225010673029408, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.22501067302941, -0.0148258464634718, -2.09243786564527, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, 
>      -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, 
>      -0.22501067302941, 0.0469698958336649, -2.37866728323154, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, 
>      -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.22501067302941, 
>      0.0127645641018549, -3.60468184093845, -0.237676950941353, -0.671726992092121, 
>      -0.902720455717881, -1.03093043315872, -1.08923963962745, -1.08923963962745, 
>      -1.03093043315872, -0.902720455717879, -0.671726992092121, -0.237676950941354, 
>      -0.0663746845686857, -1.8122859187888, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.22501067302941, -0.00687641856696633, 
>      -3.25076082791, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.9747299419738, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, 0.0713838463727453, -2.97830840520726, 
>      -0.237676950941353, -0.671726992092122, -0.90272045571788, -1.03093043315872, 
>      -1.08923963962745, -1.08923963962745, -1.03093043315872, -0.902720455717879, 
>      -0.671726992092121, -0.237676950941354, -0.0743050452533843, 
>      -2.67628816557959, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, -0.0349838095065649, 
>      -3.5430249109514, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973799, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, -0.0386783840155437, 
>      -2.12026353620009, -0.225010673029408, -0.647699465173936, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.22501067302941, -0.0455123768314332, -3.96137088020182, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, 
>      -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866002, -0.647699465173934, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.0424241694671741, -2.65672608669956, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, 
>      -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.0925355864695667, -1.01211840417381, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, 
>      -0.864615530866002, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, -0.0182371120837999, 
>      -2.47170402968995, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, 0.0504657651506745, -3.22164426312502, 
>      -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.9747299419738, 
>      -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, 
>      -0.225010673029409, 0.0606712676252324, -2.74459615242235, -0.225010673029409, 
>      -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, 
>      -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, 
>      0.0395621377159473, -1.9946579165884, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, 
>      -0.864615530866001, -0.647699465173934, -0.225010673029409, -0.0686057430183023, 
>      -2.86667282962915, -0.237676950941353, -0.671726992092122, -0.90272045571788, 
>      -1.03093043315872, -1.08923963962745, -1.08923963962745, -1.03093043315872, 
>      -0.902720455717879, -0.671726992092121, -0.237676950941354, -0.0791349203971352, 
>      -1.19764458947793, -0.225010673029409, -0.647699465173935, -0.864615530866001, 
>      -0.974729941973799, -1.00883617472156, -0.974729941973798, -0.864615530866002, 
>      -0.647699465173934, -0.22501067302941, -0.0475062351402155))
>   2: optim(unlist(betas), fn = loglikgrm, gr = scoregrm, method = con$method, 
>          hessian = Hessian, control = list(maxit = con$iter.qN, trace = as.numeric(con$verbose)), 
>          constrained = constrained)
>   1: grm(data)

I think something really isn't right but I'm not sure how to proceed? Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 0):

You can read the output starting at the bottom.  You called `grm(data)`; that is shown as `1: grm(data)` on the last line.

The `grm()` function called `optim()` with the arguments shown after `2: optim(unlist(betas), ...` starting on the third last line.

`optim()` then called an anonymous function, defined as `function (par) fn(par, ...)` with that long argument list.  Here `fn()` is probably the `loglikgrm` function from the call to `optim`, though it is possible `fn` was modified before the call.

Finally, that anonymous function called `fn(par, ...)`.

We don't know any context here, but it looks as though the problem is in the `loglikgrm` function.  If you wrote that, you need to add debugging statements (e.g. `browser()`, or `print(something)`, etc.) to see why it is generating the index into `log.pr` that R is complaining about.  If you didn't write it, it's going to be hard to debug:  you'll probably need to contact its author to figure out what's going on.

When you do, please include a reproducible example that triggers the error.

Comment: Hi thank you, I'm very new to R. I didn't write that. When you say contact the author, what do you mean? Sorry, really not a coder here.

Comment: The `grm()` function comes from a contributed package, it's not part of base R.  I believe it is in the `ltm` package (though there might be another one somewhere).  So you should contact the author of the package it came from.  If the package is `ltm`, the author is Dimitris Rizopoulos <d.rizopoulos@erasmusmc.nl>.

Comment: That is correct - the ltm package - thank you very much. Will contact him now.